# How can I save integers from a file to array?

Tags: c, arrays

I have tried for about a day and a half. Tried several methods to put my file's integers into array. Can you help please? The output I get now is the same number repeated over and over.

```
if ((nfPtr=fopen("c:\\Users\\raphaeljones\\Desktop\\newfile.dat","r"))==NULL)
{
    printf("File could not be opened\n");
}
else {
    printf("The integers you have entered are: \n");
    fscanf(nfPtr,"%d\n",&i);
    while(!feof(nfPtr)){
        for (count=0;count<=SIZE;count++){  
            fscanf(nfPtr,"%d",&array[i]);
            i++;
            printf("%d\n",i);
        }
    }
}//end else
fclose(nfPtr);
getch();    
return 0;
```

Comment: 1) Format the code. 2) Use search 3) [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: `while(!feof(nfPtr)`....are you sure?

Comment: What language/platform are you using? (ANSI C or C++?) Please clarify exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: C sorry. I want read integers from a file called 'newfile.dat'. I would like the numbers I read from file to be stored in an array called 'array'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
for (i = 0; fscanf(nfPtr, "%d", &array[i]) == 1; i++) {
   printf("%d\n", array[i]);
}
```

Provided your array is always big enough (which you usually don't know), otherwise you have to dynamically allocate space for each new element.

Comment: Wow! works man. This took me a very long time to understand. thanks

Answer (score 1):

In this code:

```
i++;
printf("%d\n",i);
```

You're incrementing the index (i) then printing it?
Did you intend to print the numbers read from the file instead?
Perhaps you want:

```
printf("%d\n",array[i]);
i++;
```

Comment: doesn't work. but thanks. i want to read how many ever integers are in the file. so i increment i. but it's wrong logic. just not sure what to tell the computer.